# Too little space between brackets and italic text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, italic, horizontal, mode

When I wrap italic text in math mode with brackets the spacing looks off to me. Consider the output of the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$f(\textit{EX})$, $f(EX)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here 'EX' is supposed to be the name of a variable, not 'E times X', so as far as I know I should use `textit{EX}` and not just `EX`. Why is there so little space between the X and the closing bracket for the first option? Typing `$f(\textit{EX}\,)$` gives better spacing, is that the 'correct' solution to this?

Comment: Why are you using `\textit` here and not `\mathit`?

Comment: I was not aware of that one! ```mathit``` does have proper spacing, so if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have really good reasons to do so you should never use `\textit` or similar in math mode. Here just use `\mathit`.

One case where one might want to use a text command is

```
R_{\textrm{sø}}
```

as the Danish vowel `ø` is not allowed in math mode. So here we switch to a text font in order to indicate rhe radius of a Danish Lake.